# Menu in the node editor is different than the one on the tutorial I'm trying to follow

Tags: mesh, node-editor, particles

I'm trying to reproduce this tutorial on my Blender 2.79 in Linux machine from this YouTube video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K3CwKkiJZN0. But the problem is somewhere in this video, instructor switches to node editor and his screen looks like this:

[image]

I just draw a red circle over that option that I don't see in my Blender when I switch to node tree. In fact, my Blender looks like this:

[image]

As you can see, I don't have that option in my node editor and unfortunately, instructor does not say anything about that option (e.g. how to load it up). I will be very grateful to let me know how I can add that option in my node tree in order to be able to reproduce this tutorial. I really appreciate any comment, suggestion, or recommendation.

**Update:**

I downloaded v2.0 of animation nodes add on and I enabled it like this:

[image]

Comment: You enabled anim-all not **animation nodes**. Those are different plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing is an addon called "animation nodes"

https://animation-nodes-manual.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/install/install.html

[image]

It is not installed by default. You would need to download it (do not Unzip the file) and install it using "Install from File"

[image]

Comment: I downloaded and installed that add on but still I can't see that option...

Comment: Did you enable the addon?

Comment: Yes I enabled it...

Comment: Which version you downloaded? mine is v2.0... and my blender is 2.79